# material-ui theme not applied automatically on AppBar?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to integrate material-ui to my project and I have some issues with custom theme settings

I created a custom theme this way

**App.js**

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: green,
        secondary: red,
    },
});

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
...}}
```

Then in a component in the substructure I create some specific css.

Now my issue is that I'm obliged to define style **appBar** with a backgroud color and apply it explicitely on the AppBar component. If I don't do one of these two operations, the bg of the appBar remains light gray

What is weired is that I get the correct green from theme.palette.primary["500"], which means the theme is correctly configured

**Header.js**

```
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    grow: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    appBar: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary["500"]
    },//...)}

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.classes = props.classes
    }

    render() {
        return (<I18n>
                    {(tsl, {i18n, t, ready}) => {
                        return (
                                <div className={this.classes.root}>
                                    <AppBar position="static" color="default" className={this.classes.appBar}>
                                        <Toolbar>...(irrelevant code)
```

I followed the examples in https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/ where the first example has the light gray color, then all the other examples have a blue bg, but there's nothing in the source code that was added to apply the blue color (in my opinion)

Any help please? thanks folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<AppBar position="static" color="primary">`.

By default `AppBar` is using the colors from the `grey` palette.

We are considering defaulting to `primary` for the `color` prop since it's not following the spec and having grey as a default for something as prominent as the app bar is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: thanks @epsilon, great answer!

I didn't get what you mean immediately, so i'll be more explicit in the answer for other users coming with the same issue: <AppBar position="static" color="primary"> fixed the issue.

Comment: @ZiedHamdi Thanks for the feedback. The answer was indeed more in depth than necessary. I added your fix to the answer.